# Open only Whatsapp and Messaging app using DataTransferManager showshareuri

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am using following code to open share UI. It opens all available share text sharing apps. Is there any way i can filter those share to Messaging and Whatsapp apps?

```
   void dataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRequest request = e.Request;
        request.Data.Properties.Title = "the title";
        request.Data.Properties.Description = "description";
        request.Data.Properties.ApplicationName = "Messeging";
        request.Data.SetText(shareText);
    }
```

Comment: you can only open whatsapp app by doing this `await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"))`

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the expected behaviour and all the apps who can read text will be shown.